# Outputting a record from the database in the ListView, the field of which coincided with the text from the textbox

Tags: c#, sql

Help! The program should output a string from the database, the value of which in the Author field fully or partially coincided with the value entered in the text box SearchTBR. It gives an error, they say, can not read the sql query (9 line).

```
private void SearchAuthorBR_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Convert.ToString(SearchTBR.Text) != "")
            {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("data source = .\\mysql; initial catalog = Library; integrated security = true");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader dr;
        cn.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = "select BookID, Author, Title, YEAR(Year), Category, Availability from Bibliography where (Author 
LIKE  '%" + SearchTBR.Text + "%')";
                cmd.Connection = cn;
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {

                    ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem(dr[0].ToString());
                    lv.SubItems.Add(dr[1].ToString());
                    lv.SubItems.Add(dr[2].ToString());
                    lv.SubItems.Add(dr[3].ToString());
                    lv.SubItems.Add(dr[4].ToString());
                    lv.SubItems.Add(dr[5].ToString());
                    listViewLLReader.Items.Add(lv);
                }
                cn.Close();
             }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ошибка. Введите параметры поиска.");
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: `YEAR(Year)` this is a reserved probably also what is `Year(Year)` you can do the following `[Year] as 'Year'  this is called `Aliasing` also read up on how to construct some basic `Select Query's`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("data source = .\\mysql; initial catalog = Library; integrated security = true");

cn.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select BookID, Author, Title, YEAR(Year), Category, Availability from Bibliography where Author LIKE  '%" + SearchTBR.Text.toString() + "%'", cn);
SqlDataReader dr;
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read()) {
    // ......
}
cn.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer you to make use of `using` as well as parameterization like the following, which may help you to get out from the current error also make your code works:

```
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
    cn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "select BookID, Author, Title, YEAR([Year]), Category, Availability from Bibliography where Author LIKE  @searchString";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchString", "%" + searchString.Text + "%"); 
    cmd.Connection = cn;
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
         ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem(dr[0].ToString());
         lv.SubItems.Add(dr[1].ToString());
         lv.SubItems.Add(dr[2].ToString());
         lv.SubItems.Add(dr[3].ToString());
         lv.SubItems.Add(dr[4].ToString());
         lv.SubItems.Add(dr[5].ToString());
         listViewLLReader.Items.Add(lv);
     }
     cn.Close();
}
```

Please Note:

> Since the `SqlCommand` implements IDisposable, `using` will helps you
>   to call them internally so that you need not to worry about
>   `closing`/`disposing` you can also enclose the connection object also
>   in using block. Whereas the parameterization helps you to protect your
>   data from injectors and also from unwanted type conversion/casting
>   errors.